# How to install cufflinks in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, plotly

I am using Python 3 on macOS. I have cufflinks installed but IDLE shows

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cufflinks'`

I have used multiple commands in the terminal such as:

```
pip install cufflinks
conda install cufflinks
conda install -c bioconda cufflinks
pip3 install cufflinks
conda-forge install cufflinks
```

I have even tried to uninstall and reinstall cufflinks multiple times but IDLE still does not work properly.

Comment: Are you sure IDLE is using the correct Python on your system?

Comment: Can you edit and add your import statement for cufflinks? Perhaps you are importing from another location?

Answer (score 8):

Met similar issue, but this works for me on Ubuntu and Jupyter notebook

```
conda install -c conda-forge cufflinks-py
```

Comment: I tried running this code and still got the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cufflinks'. After that I ran the sequence shown by @rahul-kumar-guptaand that worked.

Answer (score 8):

(make sure you have opened your cmd as an administrator or in Linux use sudo)

first of all update your pip

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

then install plotly

```
pip install plotly
```

then install cufflinks

```
pip install cufflinks
```

Answer (score 2):

### Cufflinks import problem solved

Install the module:

```
pip install cufflinks
```

First import sys module:

```
import sys
```

and then import cufflinks:

```
import cufflinks
```

I hope it works for you too..

Answer (score 1):

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 cufflinks-py
```

This worked for me ones.

Answer (score 0):

I am installing in my env under Ubuntu and Jupyter Notebook with this:

```
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} cufflinks
```

Or:

```
!{sys.executable} -m pip install cufflinks
```